# I edited readme on GitHub, now how do I squash edits

Tags: git, github

I am a total noob at this.

I have tried all the commands that other's recommended, such as..

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3 
git rebase -i
```

Those commands do not work locally, because I made the edits on GitHub, I suppose. Obviously, I need to checkout all the commits first somehow. How do I checkout all the commits and squash them. These are some simple edits to the readme that I did before I realized that I should be doing them locally.

I get a text file that look like this in the editor.

```
noop

# Rebase 2dff767..2dff767 onto 2dff767
#
# Commands:
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
```

**UPDATE:**
OK, what I did was this

```
git reset --soft HEAD~3
git commit
git push -f
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You would need to do a soft reset to the start of the ones you want to squash, commit, and then force push.

Comment: Why do you want to squash edits? What problem are you trying to solve? And are there other commits to the repo?

Comment: It seemed like something that they recommend, in order to simplify the edits for the benefit of others. There are no other commits at this time.

Comment: OK, never mind. They only recommend it fi you haven't committed yet.

Comment: Yes; once your local repository has gone out the door, it's a bad idea to re-write history. You can cause all sorts of chaos down the line. Now, if you're the only user of this github repository, you can probably get away with it. Otherwise, your co-workers are likely to appear at your door with a tire iron to explain to you the penalties for breaking the build.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you have to pull the changes down, fix up the branch locally and push with force.  It might go something like:

```
git pull
git rebase -i HEAD~3
git push -f
```

Comment: I am pretty sure I tried this, but it could not find the revisions that I did online for some reason. The soft reset seems to have done the trick. Thanks!