# edited readme online on github

Tags: git, github, conflict

So I am so new to git and github that not even this other thread helped me [I edited readme on GitHub, now how do I squash edits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17056371/i-edited-readme-on-github-now-how-do-i-squash-edits)

I am not familiar with rebase, or --soft, nor do I understand the head -3.

But I did that same mistake, edited my README online at github.com and now it won't let me push my most recent commit.

I don't want to pull the entire rep from github, because I would loose last changes on local machine.

I have already committed the changes on my local machine.

Can I use the stash that I have heard about and then pull entire rep down, and again insert those last changes or does it not work that way?

I basically only use the add, commit and push commands for the code updates I do...

Sorry if this is an all too newbie question for this forum..

Comment: You just need to pull from github, merge if there are any conflicts, and push.

Comment: so pulling will not overwrite my last local changes?

Comment: seems to have worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have changes locally to README, then it is as simple as:

```
git pull
```

If you have local changes to README, then after the `git pull`, resolve the conflicts and `git push`.  If you wish just to wipe out the changes done on github and replace with you local changes:

```
git push -f
```